# How to use DocuSign API with React.js?

Tags: reactjs, docusignapi

I need to do a POC of some DocuSign e-Signature features in a React.js environment. For starters, I would like to play with the examples as mentioned here https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/tree/master/lib/eSignature. The official documentation is not self explanatory on how to use these in a React.js code repo(exported from create-react-app). Neither could I find some relevant samples for a reference. Would appreciate if anyone can guide me on how can I port the examples in this repo https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node in a React.js environment.

Comment: Were you able to get the POC done? as I am looking for the same.

Comment: @AbdulMannan : i ended up having my server app use the Node.js SDK and expose required APIs for use at frontend.

Answer (score 0):

For React.JS:

1. You can make a direct API call from your React app. In this case you will not use the node.js SDK (it only works with Node.js). The API call is the create envelope call documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/

You can see an example of the API call here: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-bash/blob/master/examples/eSignature/eg017SetTemplateTabValues.sh#L68

You will also need to implement a private CORS gateway. We have an article on doing so plus code examples: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-building-single-page-applications-with-docusign-and-cors-part-2
2.  Alternative is for your React app to ask your server app to call DocuSign. Your server app could use the Node.js SDK.